# Possible structures in 1D

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals, structure-formation

Suppose we have 1D crystal of several types of atoms.

How many fundamentally different structures exist?

The obvious are *the grid* and *the random distribution*.

Substitution system A -> ABA, B -> BBB
produces approximations to *fractal* Cantor set.

According to Salvatore Torquato, distribution of non-trivial zeros of Riemann's zeta function is example of 1D *disordered hyperuniformity*.

Are there examples of fundamentally different structures?

Comment: What makes two structures "fundamentally different"?

Comment: @probably_someone, may be:   
- topological dimension   
- correlation function  
etc

Comment: This seems more about math than physics. The “atoms” and the “crystal” are irrelevant. You are just arranging various things on a line.

Comment: Which specific classes of structures qualify as "a grid"? For example, must adjacent atoms be evenly spaced?